# No valida mi Button de Ingreso AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

ando armando un simple login con conexion a un servidor remoto como 000webhost pero lo que pasa es que mi boton "INGRESAR" no realizar ninguna acción, ya le di milvueltas al codigo y nada. Espero su ayuda. Gracias.

```
        btnEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String user_id=tvUser.getText().toString();
            final String user_password=tvPassWord.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean succes = jsonResponse.getBoolean("succes");
                        if(succes){
                            String user_nombre = jsonResponse.getString("user_nombre");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenuPrincipal.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                            intent.putExtra("user_nombre",user_nombre);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Error al ingesar.").setNegativeButton("Reintentar",null).create().show();
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
```

Parte de mi LoginRequest

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String ruta="https://lalycorp.000webhostapp.com/login.php";
private Map<String,String> params;
public LoginRequest(String user_id, String user_password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST, ruta,listener,null);
    params=new HashMap<>();
    params.put("user_id",user_id+"");
    params.put("user_pass",user_password+"");
}

@Override
public Map<String,String> getParams() {return params;}
```

Mi codigo login.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","id7687347_lalycorp","lalycorp","id7687347_lalycorp");

$username = $_POST["id_user"];
$password = $_POST["id_contra"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM laly_user WHERE id_user = ? AND id_contra = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$user_id,$user_nombre);

$response = array();
$response["success"]=false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"]=true;
    $response["id_user"]=$user_id;
    $response["id_nombre"]=$user_nombre;        
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Esto es lo que me lanza en el log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como que no hace nada? Has probado a poner logs o puntos de interrupción para ver hasta donde te llega?

Comment: Donde declaras la botón btnEntrar? Y como es la vista en que lo utilizas?

Comment: En el log no me salta ningún error, por eso me parece raro que no realice ninguna acción. Lo declaro así  btnEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

Comment: Bien, esa parte está bien. Y donde tienes el listener del onclick?

Comment: El problema es que estas creando un response.listener pero en ningun momento estas ejecutando el request.

Comment: Lo llamo después de terminar mi Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() lo llamo así como `LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(user_id,user_password,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);`

Comment: te recomendaría que pongas log en los onclick, así te aseguras si entra o no al dar click en el botón.